# Künneth formula for algebraic de Rham cohomology

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, positive-characteristic, derham-cohomology

Let $X$ and $Y$ be finite type schemes over a field $k$, and let $H^i(X/k)$ denote the $i$-th algebraic de Rham cohomology group of $X$ over $k$.  I'm interested in the extent to which a Künneth formula
$$
H^n(X \times Y/k) \cong \bigoplus_{i + j = n} H^i(X/k) \otimes_k H^j(Y/k)
$$
holds.  I'm aware that by comparing with singular cohomology, such a formula holds whenever $X$ and $Y$ are smooth varieties and the characteristic of $k$ is zero.  I'm also aware that regardless of the characteristic of the ground field, we have an isomorphism
$$
R\Gamma(X, \Omega^*_{X/k}) \otimes^L_k R\Gamma(Y, \Omega^*_{Y/k}) \cong R\Gamma(X \times Y, \Omega^*_{X \times Y})
$$
in $D(k)$ whenever $X$ and $Y$ are smooth, quasicompact, and have affine diagonal (in particular this doesn't seem to apply to projective varieties), but I'm unsure how this isomorphism in the derived category relates to taking cohomology groups.

**To what extent does the Künneth decomposition above hold for smooth finite type schemes over a field of positive characteristic?**

Comment: Why doesn't "smooth, quasicompact, and affine diagonal" apply to projective varieties?

Comment: The second formula implies the first because all $k$-modules are flat when $k$ is a field. Normally, you would have to worry about the higher $Tor$ groups.

Comment: @WillSawin I think I misunderstand the definitions.  Could you define what it means for a scheme to have affine diagonal?

Comment: @DonuArapura I see, thanks!  So will this implication fail in general over rings of characteristic $p$?

Comment: A scheme has affine diagonal if the diagonal morphism $X \to X\times X$ is affine in the sense that the inverse image of any affine is affine. Being separated is sufficient to have affine diagonal since closed immersions are affine. An example of a scheme without affine diagonal is the affine plane with doubled origin.

Comment: If you have schemes over a ring $R$, take the cotangent complex relative to $R$, and then take fiber products over $R$, you may have a more complicated formula with Tor terms, depending on the ring $R$ and the schemes $X,Y$.

Comment: @WillSawin I see.  Thanks very much!